# OpenCV C++ to C conversion

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

if in openCV with C++ API while creating a rotation matrix if I write

```
       Mat rot_matrix = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center, angle, 1.0);
```

then how should I write it in openCV with C? What should I write instead of Mat? Is it like this:-

```
         CvMat* rot_mat =cv2DRotationMatrix( center, angle, scale, rot );
```

Is the above declaration correct? If yes, then how can I represent it in wrap affine function?
Is it like this:-

```
         cvWarpAffine( src, dst, rot_mat);
```

Comment: The best way is to try it... and you don't need to write CvMat* rot_mat it's enough to do: cv2DRotationMatrix(center,angle,scale,rot_mat) and then cvWarpAffine(src,dst,rot_mat)

Comment: @TheNewOne I tried your way but I am getting error as error: ‘rot_mat’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: You need to declare it above, CvMat * rot_mat=cvCreateMat(rows,cols,type). anyway if the problem is the code post your complete code and errors.

Comment: @TheNewOne why is CvMat not taking values other than 2,3 ? Why can't it be other rows or columns?

Comment: it can have more... but rotation matrix is 2x3 (actually it can be 2x2 but it takes the center parameter too. no one said that CvMat *has to be* 2x3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused according to our little chat at the comments sector, so I decided to write you an answer that would try to make it a bit clearer.

First for the original question as you wrote `Mat` is indeed C++ form.

In C you use `CvMat` but the function  `cv2DRotationMatrix()` already takes `CvMat *` as part of the parameters therefore it can be used like that:

```
 cv2DRotationMatrix(center,angle,scale,rot_mat);
```

**where:**

- center is `CvPoint2D32f`, the center of the rotation in the source image (width/2,height/2).
- angle – The desired rotation angle(in degrees).
- scale – Isotropic scale factor (1 means the picture would be kept at the same size)
- mapMatrix – Pointer to the destination matrix (your 2x3 matrix that would be used as the rotation matrix)

Now rot_mat would hold the rotation matrix:

[image]

**where:**

[image]

Now you would like to calculate the position of each pixel after rotating the whole picture in x degrees (an *Affine transformation* on the pixels/pciture/image).

At this stage you have the **rotation matrix** that is being used in the *affine transformation* and you want to do the *affine transformation* (rotating the image) so you can use the function `cvWarpAffine()`

**in our case:**

```
cvWarpAffine( src, dst, rot_mat );
```

**where:**

- src – Source image
- dst – Destination image
- rot_mat as our mapMatrix(transformation matrix)

*there is also a fourth parameter which is flag but the default is o.k for our case.

**what it does?**

transforms the source image using the specified matrix:

[image]

[image]

*or in simpler words as I described before it "just" calculates the new position for each pixel after the rotation (using rotation matrix - as input to the affine function).

rot_mat should be 2x3 mat - you can create it by calling `cvCreateMat()`.

src,dst are `IplImage *` (because we said it's c code).

*The technical aspect of the function is from:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/geometric_image_transformations.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like porting C++ program to C. As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV#Programming_language), there are C interfaces which you can look for your purpose.

Declarations seems right provided the parameters are not reference but pointers since C does not support reference.

You can use pointers to wrap the class objects. It will be like:

```
CvMat * cv2dRotationMatrix( CvPoint *, CvAngle *, float );
```

As you have pointed out that you need to wrap C++ functions under a pure C function.